Bounding the Stationary Expectation of a Stochastic Process using Perturbation Theory
I'm examining a stochastic process on a full binary tree with $n$ leaves where the nodes can be black or white. I also have a cost function $C$ that takes in a binary tree and a coloring of the nodes and returns a cost.
I have that the transition matrix $P = ((1-p)I + pA)((1-p)I + pB)$ where $p$ is an arbitrarily small constant. In other words, in each round, I apply the transition matrix $A$ with probability $p$ and then apply the transition matrix $B$ with probability $p$. $A$ can only decrease the number of blank nodes in the tree whereas $B$ can only increase the number of black nodes in the tree. Thus, the transition matrix has the form $$(1-p)^2I + p(1-p)A + p(1-p)B + p^2 AB$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.
I can ensure that $p$ is an arbitrarily small constant. It's easy to compute the transition matrix and stationary distribution $0.5A + 0.5B$, but it's hard to compute the transition matrix and stationary distribution of $AB$. Thus, I'd like to argue that the $p^2AB$ term doesn't matter that much for the stationary distribution. I tried to use some bounds from this paper but they are all too lossy or require me to compute or at least bound the group inverse of $A$.
I feel like there's a simpler solution, since applying $AB$ to the stationary distribution of $0.5A + 0.5B$ would only increase the cost, as $B$ coming after $A$ might possibly improve the damage caused by $A$. I'm wondering if there are any "directed perturbation" results that might help me get rid of this $AB$ term without too much computation.
(Notice that I can also model this as an inhomogenous Markov process where on odd rounds the transition matrix is helpful and on even rounds the transition matrix hurts, and somehow compare this to a random homogenous random process where I apply the odd/even matrix with probability 1/2. However, I couldn't find any promising results in this direction.)
